# Saving User datas in Shared Prefererences or Retrieving datas from firebase in every session

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

I am developing a role-based application for my school using android studio with firebase. I couldn't make a decision about how can i display or control user datas.

I am using firestore for storing user datas, for example; name,role,class.
When user starts activity, the activity should fetch user datas from it's own document, right?

But i didn't want to read datas in every deploy of application. So i used shared preferences for storing datas. However it complexed code and reduced reusability.
Also since my application is role-based, it's hard to check if user is admin **from shared preferences**

### Reading user document in every deploy of application

**pros**: Everything seems fine except bill

**cons**: Bills of read operations

### Storing in shared preferences

**pros**: Seems economic

**const**: complex code, reusability is low, if else count is high

---

**Which one is better?**

*Or do you have any suggestions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database and local storage have 2 separate use cases. Since you say that you need to check if an user is admin, you will probably need a database on the internet to validate that yourself, not store it on the local device.

If you don't need to validate anything or share data between devices/users or whatever, you can use local storage. But shared preferences should be used to store small data, key-value data only. If you want to store more complex data and more data in general, use sqlite(https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

As for the billing, if price is an issue you can always setup your own http server with a postgresql database for example.

Comment: i have written firebase security rules, so i can check if user is an admin or not but before checking in server i control in local device .

Comment: So you probably do need a database but if the only con is billing you might have to just make your own http server to lower cost.

Comment: i have used mysql in this project before firebase and i have not experience with postgresql so can i use mysql instead of postgesql

Comment: Yeah, they should both work.